# Nuxt. Using .env variables in appConfig.ts file

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3, .env

I am tring to use .env variable in my Nuxt app's app config file, is it real?

I am doing something like this [image: screenshot of code example], and using my variable like [image], i am doing this, cause where i have some ui layer that need dynamic changed variable depending on it's runing mode. My problem is on app builiding or loading i can get my variable but after, my variable becomes undefined

Answer (score 0):

U can't get .env variable in app config if component that uses variable is client only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).